# Accessing my Rails webrick behind proxy?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, firewall, ruby-on-rails

In my mackbook, when I try to connect to my rails application in office I can't , in the office there are some http proxy , and when I run my rails like this :

```
sudo rails s -p8080
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-03-20 12:49:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-03-20 12:49:34] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2012-03-20 12:49:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=17439 port=8080
```

The local IP is :

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether f8:1e:df:d8:8c:25 
inet6 fe80::fa1e:dfff:fed8:8c25%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
inet 10.21.21.240 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.21.21.255
media: autoselect
status: active
```

so when I try in the browser to trigger localhost:8080 or 10.21.21.240:8080 , it seems that I can't trigger my application

[image]

as for the proxy check out the following : 
[image]

Any Ideas ?

The weird thing is that when I try to curl I get some response and work :

```
curl http://10.21.21.240:8080 
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://10.21.21.240:8080/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your office proxy probably knows how to get to the public Internet, but not your private network.

In your proxy settings, add an entry to bypass the proxy for the `10/8` network (that means any 10.x.y.z address). So make that text field look like this:

```
*.local, 169.254/16, 10/8
```

Note that `curl` is a portable open source tool that doesn't tend to adopt any platform-specific technologies when it can avoid it, so it almost certainly doesn't honor Mac OS X's proxy settings (unlike most GUI/Cocoa browsers would). That would explain why curl is working while your GUI-based browser is not.